# Why doesn't foward declaration of class work when class is included in another class

Tags: c++, class, include, declaration, forward-declaration

This compiles

```
#include "Sprite.h"

class GameObject
{
  public:
      int x, y, w, h;
      Sprite sprite;
  public:
    GameObject();
    GameObject(int _x, int _y, int _w, int _h);
    virtual ~GameObject();
};
```

This doesn't

```
class Sprite;

class GameObject
{
  public:
      int x, y, w, h;
      Sprite sprite;
  public:
    GameObject();
    GameObject(int _x, int _y, int _w, int _h);
    virtual ~GameObject();
};
```

I know that I could forward declare and use pointer for Sprite but why doesn't forward declaration works here. 
Doesn't "class Sprite;" tells that Sprite exists? 
I'm trying #include as much classes in .cpp and avoid it in .h at any cost.
Also classes are not including each other so there is no need to use Sprite*.
I guess my understanding of what forward declaring is is wrong or something because I don't see a reason why this doesn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretend you're the compiler. Without having a complete declaration of `Sprite` at your disposal, how is it possible to determine whether the `Sprite` is only one byte big, or one hundred thousand bytes big?

You don't need to know much about the class when you only need a pointer to the class (or a reference to a class, or a few other minor things); but when you need to actually use the class, a mere forward declaration is not sufficient. It's not always enough to know that "`Sprite` exists"; sometimes it's necessary to know how big it is, too. And without a complete declaration, that's not possible.

Comment: So the reason it works with pointers is because the only thing pointer needs to know is the size of memory address witch is always same?

Comment: Cool, that sums it up, I also learn something about pointers, thanks man

Answer (score 2):

Forward declarations only work with references or pointers, if the type appears in the depending class declaration.

```
class Sprite;

class GameObject
{
  public:
      int x, y, w, h;
      Sprite* sprite; // <<<<
  // or Sprite& sprite;
  public:
    GameObject();
    GameObject(int _x, int _y, int _w, int _h);
    virtual ~GameObject();
};
```

Care to include the `Sprite.h` file in your implementation, and initialize the member in your constructor implementation ideally (a reference would require that strictly).

Answer (score 1):

`Sprite` can't be [incomplete type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type#Incomplete_type) here, because the size and layout of it must be known as the non-static member of class `GameObject`.

(Note the 3rd one)

> Any of the following contexts requires class `T` to be complete:
>
> ```
> definition or function call to a function with return type T or argument type T;
> definition of an object of type T;
> declaration of a non-static class data member of type T;
> new-expression for an object of type T or an array whose element type is T;
> lvalue-to-rvalue conversion applied to a glvalue of type T;
> an implicit or explicit conversion to type T;
> a standard conversion, dynamic_cast, or static_cast to type T* or T&, except when converting from the null pointer constant or from a pointer to void;
> class member access operator applied to an expression of type T;
> typeid, sizeof, or alignof operator applied to type T;
> arithmetic operator applied to a pointer to T;
> definition of a class with base class T;
> assignment to an lvalue of type T;
> a catch-clause for an exception of type T, T&, or T*.
> ```

On the other hand, if you declare it as pointer or reference, incomplete type is fine and forward declaration will be allowed.